# How to add keyListener to class that extends Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, awt, keylistener

Thread does not contain a method called addKeyListener() but is there a way to add the addKeylistener method to the thread? I need to listen for key strokes.

```
public class TypeHelperMain extends Thread implements KeyListener    
    {


        public TypeHelperMain(){

            addKeyListener(this);

        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid,You are going in a wrong direction.Why a thread need key listener?

Comment: The thread runs in the background and picks up key strokes.

Comment: @user2708073 You don't need a thread to do this

Comment: But is there no way to do it with the thread?

Comment: You could implement runnable on a JComponent, and add a keylistener to that

Comment: @user2708073 No. You would have to extend `JComponent`, but you are already extending `Thread`, which doesn't support `KeyListener`. In fact it doesn't make sense to have a non-UI component which listens to the keyboard. It can make sense if you are planning to do a KeyLogger, but you can't do it with plain java

Comment: Java can only catch key events when it's the active window. It can not hook the OS' keyboard events. And when it is the active window, all key events go to at least the JFrame if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I am using the blackberry API. No it is not a keylogger.

Comment: @user2708073 Stating specifically that it isn't a keylogger just makes us more suspicious.

Comment: @user2708073: you will have to consult the Javadocs for the Blackberry API.  There will be some user interface layer that you can use to respond to input events.  The Java Thread API deals with threads, not user interface events.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this in a Swing application, then I would recommend this approach:

```java
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(
        new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
                    System.out.println("Captured: " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
                }
                return false; // allowing it to be dispatched further
            }
        });
```

Source: http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2011/09/16/java-global-jframe-key-listener/